# Check whether a function is one-to-one and onto

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

If $f(x) = \log_{x^3}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$, 
check whether $f$ is one-to-one and onto where $x\in R^+\setminus\{1\}$. Also write the range of $f$.

Alright, if $f(m) = f(n)$ and if we would prove $m=n$ it would be a one-to-one function. Since $f(x)=\ln(\sqrt{x})/\ln(x^3)$ I equated them, I'm not quite sure how I would verify $m=n$ or $m≠n$.

I proved until $m^n=n^m$ so It can't be one-one since $m \neq n$, right? So function is not one-to-one or onto? Is that correct?

Comment: When you haven't specified what the target range is, it's impossible to answer whether the function is onto. Any function is onto it's image.

Comment: Ah Alright, how do I prove it's one-to-one or not one-to-one

Comment: What about showing a little self effort? What did you try, what have you done so far to solve your problem? Add this to your question, so that it won't look like you're expecting someone else to do all your work for you.

Comment: Alright, if f(m) = f(n) and if we would prove m=n it would be a one-to-one function. since $\log _{x^3\left(\sqrt{x}\right)\:=\:\frac{\ln \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{ln\left(x^3\right)}}$ I equated them, I'm not quite sure how I would verify m=n or m$\ne$n

Comment: I proved until $m^n=n^m$ so It can't be one-one since $m\ne n$ right? So function is not one-to-one or onto? Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Hints: observe that for **any** $\;1\neq x>0\;$ we have

$$\log_{x^3}\sqrt x=\frac12\log_{x^3}x=\frac12\frac{\log x}{\log x^3}=\frac16$$

Answer now your question.

Comment: So the function returns a constant of 1/6 for whatever x so it's a many-to-one function. And range of $f$ is 1/6?

Comment: Yes...and perhaps you should go over your notes if you need to ask that.